# Use UITextField entry as array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, textfield

In iOS I am trying to make it so that a user entered UITextField entry is the only value of my array.  Right now, every new UITextField entry keeps adding values to the array. I only want the current UITextField entry.

Is there something I can easily add so that the most current UITextField entry is the only value used in the array?

Right now I have this in my ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
    NSString * input=textfield.text;

    Label.text=input;

    [self resignFirstResponder];

    [array4 addObject:self.textfield.text];

    NSLog(@"array: %@", array4);
}
```

Comment: Just change [array4 addObject:self.textfield.text]; to self.array4 = [[NSMutableArray Alloc] initWithObject : self.textfield.tex];

Please ignore syntax error as I have written in obj c without xcode, simply what I am doing in this line is just changing array element when new textfield text is added.

Comment: if array4.contains(textfield.text) { return }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `array4` to only have one value of `self.textfield.text` then change:

```
[array4 addObject:self.textfield.text];
```

to:

```
array4 = @[ self.textfield.text ];
```

That assigns a new, single-element array to `array4`.